# Escape special characters from variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, special-characters

I have

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
search="ldo_vrf18 {"
replace="$search"'                      compatible = "regulator-fixed";
                        regulator-name = "vrf18";
                        regulator-min-microvolt = <1800000>;
                        regulator-max-microvolt = <1800000>;
                        regulator-enable-ramp-delay = <120>;'
sed -i "s/$search/$replace/g" output.file
```

The result is

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 62: unterminated `s' command
```

I suspect some values arent being escape in `replace`. Is there a way to escape them?
I have tried `sed -i 's/'"$search"'/'"$replace"'/g' output.file` with the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the newlines in the `$replace` variable, which are interpreted by `sed` as end of command.

In order to solve that in GNU `sed`, you'll need to replace the new lines in your `$replace` variable with a literal `\n`:

```
replace=${replace//$'\n'/\\n}
```

**Note:** The solution above will not work in all `sed` implementations, as it's an extended feature in some versions (for instance, in GNU `sed`). According to the [POSIX standards](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/sed.html#tag_04_126_13_03):

> Each embedded *<newline>* in the text shall be preceded by a
> backslash. Other backslashes in text shall be removed<sup>+</sup>, and the
> following character shall be treated literally.

So on POSIX `sed`, the literal `\n` will lose it's meaning as a newline and be treated just as a literal `n` character. For a portable solution that would work on all `sed` implementations, precede the actual newlines with a backslash:

```
replace=${replace//$'\n'/\\$'\n'}
```

---

<sub><sup>+</sup> Except for backslash followed by a digit:</sub>

> **The characters `"\n"`, where `n` is a digit**, shall be replaced by the
> text matched by the corresponding backreference expression. [...] For
> **each other backslash ( '`\`' ) encountered, the following character
> shall lose its special meaning** (if any).

Comment: And note that _inserting newlines with `\n` using the `s` command_ is an extended feature that not all `sed` implementations have.  To do it portably, escape each literal newline with a backslash.

Comment: @Kusalananda oh, I see what you mean: `replace=${replace//$'\n'/\\$'\n'}` ?

Comment: Standard `sed` (as found on e.g. some BSD systems) does not understand that `\n` means a literal newline when it occurs in the replacement text and will insert an `n` instead.  To be portable, you would have to ensure that each literal newline in `$replace` is escaped.  If you use `replace=${replace//$'\n'/\\$'\n'}` in bash, that would do it.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Kusalananda FWIW, when I use the `--posix` flag on my GNU `sed` to "disable all GNU extensions", it still works with the literal `\n` (like in my answer) and doesn't insert `n` character.

Comment: Well, that's a bug.  The POSIX standard say that the only special backslash sequence is a backslash followed by a digit in the range 1 to 9. _Any other backslash sequence_ removes the special meaning of the following character, if any (for example, `\&` means a literal `&` rather than the matched text). So `\n` mean, literally, "an ordinary n". It also says: "A line can be split by substituting a newline into it. The application shall escape the newline in the replacement by preceding it by a backslash."

Comment: @Kusalananda just for the sake of completeness and after a further research, it's not strictly a bug. From POSIX: _The meaning of a `'\'` immediately followed by any character other than '`&`', `'\'`, a digit, or the delimiter character used for this command, **is unspecified**._ See also [this](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=54614) bug report.

Comment: Good call. I the fact that `\n` inserts a newline is hidden away in a single place in the `info` documentation of GNU `sed`, so it's at least documented. It's still not portable though.